# int value changing when passing it into a function

Tags: c

I'm passing in an int to a function in my lame program.  It's passing in a number to convert it to a binary representation as an int array.

```
typedef int bool;

bool* conv2bin(int num)
{
    blah blah blah return binary as bool array
}
```

I pass in 78 and if I printf() immediately after it's passed in, I get 781237412753-124?

I'm new to C (coming from C++) so please tell me if I'm doing something really dumb?

This seems like it should be really easy but it isn't...?

EDIT:

Have I done goofed:

```
printf("%d", num);
```

EDIT 2:
It has to be something with the int because at the end of the function, it checks to see if we subtracted numbers sufficiently to get to num==0 but it says we're not at 0.  It's doing really weird things.  It also says that the binary is 0000000001001111, and it should be 0000000001001110.

Edit 3:

Wow I suck.  Thank you Floris!  It's been a long day.

Comment: Please show your `printf` statement. I am 99% sure you have the format string wrong.

Comment: blah blah does not compile

Comment: Change your `printf` to `printf("%d\n", num);` - I bet you will now see that there is a carriage return after the `78` (you are printing two or more numbers back to back). The error is somewhere else in your code. Show more.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing here…
Your printout starts with the correct two digits: `78`.

But if you do not include a `\n` at the end of your formatting string, then the next thing you print will be concatenated. As will the next thing, and the next.

I suspect your problem will disappear when you change your print statement to

```
printf("%d\n", num);
```